# When using Twitter Bootstrap is is better for performance to init plugins in JavaScript or via Data Attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When using twitter bootstrap you can attach plugins in your Javascript or via data attributes. For example a modal can be made like this:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal">Hello</div>
```

Or like this:

```
In the HTML:

<a href="#" class="launch-modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal">Hello</div>

In the js file:

$('.launch-modal').on('click', function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

At first I thought using data attributes would be slower since bootstrap probably scans the entire page on dom ready to see which (if any) elements are attached to what plugins, but then realized if this is the case bootstrap is doing this scanning regardless whether you attach plugins via data attributes of not in order to make the necessary check.

Is there any performance benefits of one over the other?

Comment: It's initialisation, it probably doesn't matter. What the init code actually does will dominate this.

Comment: You could create a new test case at http://jsperf.com/

Comment: I'd say that the data attributes are slower, but only by virtue of having to read them from the DOM and put them into options hashes. This is probably negligible compared to the result of calling those plugins which causes restyling and re-rendering.